# Building the P compiler on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, p-lang

I'm having trouble building [Microsoft's P language compiler](https://github.com/p-org/P) on Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6.

Relevant portions of the build log (`cd Bld; ./build.sh`):

```
~/workspace/P/Bld
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 8.0.0.8000038
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 8.0.0.8000038
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/jlieberm/workspace/P/Bld/build
Scanning dependencies of target Prt
[ 12%] Building C object Prt/CMakeFiles/Prt.dir/API/PrtUser.c.o
In file included from /Users/jlieberm/workspace/P/Src/Prt/API/PrtUser.c:1:
In file included from /Users/jlieberm/workspace/P/Src/Prt/API/PrtUser.h:9:
In file included from /Users/jlieberm/workspace/P/Src/Prt/Core/PrtExecution.h:4:
In file included from /Users/jlieberm/workspace/P/Src/Prt/API/Prt.h:9:
In file included from /Users/jlieberm/workspace/P/Src/Prt/API/PrtProgram.h:14:
/Users/jlieberm/workspace/P/Src/Prt/API/PrtValues.h:255:8: error: unknown type
      name 'PRT_FUN_PARAM_STATUS'
                _In_ PRT_FUN_PARAM_STATUS status,
                     ^
/Users/jlieberm/workspace/P/Src/Prt/API/PrtValues.h:326:8: error: unknown type
      name 'PRT_FUN_PARAM_STATUS'
                _In_ PRT_FUN_PARAM_STATUS status,
                     ^
/Users/jlieberm/workspace/P/Src/Prt/API/PrtValues.h:436:8: error: unknown type
      name 'PRT_FUN_PARAM_STATUS'
                _In_ PRT_FUN_PARAM_STATUS status,
                     ^
In file included from /Users/jlieberm/workspace/P/Src/Prt/API/PrtUser.c:1:
In file included from /Users/jlieberm/workspace/P/Src/Prt/API/PrtUser.h:9:
/Users/jlieberm/workspace/P/Src/Prt/Core/PrtExecution.h:164:122: error: unknown
      type name 'PRT_FUN_PARAM_STATUS'
  ...PRT_MACHINEINST_PRIV * context, _In_ PRT_UINT32 varIndex, _In_ PRT_FUN_P...
                                                                    ^
/Users/jlieberm/workspace/P/Src/Prt/Core/PrtExecution.h:184:8: error: unknown
      type name 'PRT_FUN_PARAM_STATUS'
                _In_ PRT_FUN_PARAM_STATUS status,
                     ^
/Users/jlieberm/workspace/P/Src/Prt/Core/PrtExecution.h:500:8: error: unknown
      type name 'PRT_FUN_PARAM_STATUS'
                _In_ PRT_FUN_PARAM_STATUS       payloadStatus,
                     ^
/Users/jlieberm/workspace/P/Src/Prt/API/PrtUser.c:508:3: error: use of
      undeclared identifier 'PRT_FUN_PARAM_STATUS'
                PRT_FUN_PARAM_STATUS argStatus = va_arg(argp, PRT_FUN_PA...
                ^
7 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [Prt/CMakeFiles/Prt.dir/API/PrtUser.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Prt/CMakeFiles/Prt.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am using mono 4.6.0 stable and cmake 3.6.2, which meet the minimum requirements in the [P build guide for OS X and Linux](https://github.com/p-org/P/wiki/Build-P-on-Ubuntu-and-OSX).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related meta: [What tag should I use to ask questions about the P programming language?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335975/2415822)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug with the source code.  The P team failed to include the `PRT_FUN_PARAM_STATUS` enum declaration in `PrtValues.h`:

```
typedef enum PRT_FUN_PARAM_STATUS
{
    PRT_FUN_PARAM_CLONE,
    PRT_FUN_PARAM_SWAP,
    PRT_FUN_PARAM_XFER
} PRT_FUN_PARAM_STATUS;
```

Fixed with [`1fd291c`](https://github.com/p-org/P/commit/1fd291cfb697b8c2bb2214a04d6b6f8d907c181c).